# Facebook graph api feed returning an empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a facebook graph api call to get a public(i.e. OPEN) group's feed.

When I go to the group's site there's quite a large feed, but when I issue the API call, I get an empty array.

I tried using an access_token parameter received from the group's adminitrator, but I still got nothing.

Do I have to request some specific permissions to receive the feed?

Note that on *some* pages I can get all data without extra permissions - e.g. the cocacola page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?#{ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

My end goal is to have a list of all recent feed activity for the group on a third-party page.

Answer (score 0):

Page access tokens are diffirent from user access tokens. So if you had an administrator access token, you have to get a list of pages that admin owns. Then in that list you can find page specific acces tokens. After gathering page access_token you can make the API call. But also you have to get Page access permissions.

1) GET admin's pages array with access_tokens

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[ADMIN-FB-ID]/accounts?access_token=[ADMIN-ACC-TOK]
```

2) Then get the page access token from returning array

3) Finally you can call page's feed api.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Right. But can I display this data to users just browsing the site? without asking them to authenticate, etc.